# Как правильно использовать функцию CONVERT() в MS SQL

Tags: c#, база-данных, visual-studio, sql-server

Мне необходимо сконвертировать значение которое выгружается из БД в DataGridView. На данный момент при отображении даты(число, месяц, год. в таблице использую формат date) в DataGridView автоматически добавляется значение времени равное 00:00:00. Я выяснил что можно использовать функцию CONVERT() для обрезки времени. Сама команда должна выглядеть как то так:

```
SELECT CONVERT(data_type(),expression,style)
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно оформить эту команду, где ее необходимо разместить(в описании самой таблицы или под ней или в каком то другом месте)?